# SQL : Pivot a two text columns table?

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm new to SQL and the Pivot function.
I want to pivot the following table:

```
name   value
-----  -----
name1  value1  
name2  value2  
name3  value3
```

To:

```
name1   name2   name3  
------  ------  ------
value1  value2  value3
```

Any idea how I can do it? Because when I read about the pivot function it required an accumulation function, but I want to keep it as strings.

Comment: First of all, is this SQL Server 2005+?. And you can use an aggregate function, `MIN` or `MAX` will do just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bogus aggregate function applicable to strings, such as `MIN`.

But you have to list the `nameX` columns manually, so if you want to pivot for unlimited/unknown number of columns, you'll have to dynamically construct the SQL clause.

Comment: Thanks, the "min" or "max" did it.